# How to customize drupal search to show only taxonomy view pages?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm stuck and need your help!

**Setting**:

- I have a Drupal 6 website and activated the view for taxonomy term pages.
- On my website a taxonomy page is composed of several different content types.
- All the different content pieces are tight together by the shared taxonomy term and displayed by the taxonomy view.

**Problem**:

- When searching for keywords, I just want the taxonomy pages to show up. All other content types should not be displayed. How do I do that?

Thx 123kit

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but not 100% sure. Can you give a specific example of what you want on the search results page?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do search in Drupal. The simple ones, for sites without lots of content is just use the built in search with Drupal, or build a view with exposed filters.

If you do the latter you are able to decide what is searchable, so you can make a search page for taxonomy terms only, one for articles etc. I'm not sure what exactly you want to be searchable, but if it's not too complex. it should be doable by setting up a view and using exposed filters.